# How to setup ycm on centos 6.6?

Tags: gcc, vim

Recently I'm trying to setup YCM on system of centos 6.6,however the system doesn't provide gcc of version high enough to support the work of clang.It is quite a trouble for me to update the gcc,more directly the lib that is required by clang,here is log when attempting to execute clang.

```
clang: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by clang)
clang: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by clang)
clang: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by clang)
clang: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by clang)
clang: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by clang)
clang: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by clang)
```

Is there any better way to setup YCM?

Comment: Why not post an issue in YCM github?